# Configure OpenCV2.3.0 on CentOS and run jar file

Tags: opencv

I am getting the exception while running a jar file from CentOS 5.7 x86_64 command prompt. Where as it is working on CentOS 6.2 x86_64. The jar file is loading an xml file of openCV and it is producing the error like I have copied here.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libjniopencv_core3672406464017531068.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /opt/lampp/htdocs/k_project_1/innefu/OpenCV-2.3.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1646)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:352)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:285)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:129)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:305)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:305)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:91)
at com.innefu.faceDetect.ImgFaceDetectNew.main(ImgFaceDetectNew.java:68)
```

While I have configured Opencv-2.0.0 on CentOS 5.7 machine but it is producing the same error. I have also export the path of lib and bin folder of OpenCV. 
   OpenCv 2.3.0 is producing error while trying to configure. So, I have copied the configured OpenCV-2.3.0 from CentOS 6.2 to the CentOS 5.7. But in both the situation error is same. Please provide suggestions.

Thanks